# How to add Button to a BottomTabNavigator on React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

My goal is to have both Top and Bottom navigation bar for `Home, Dashboard, and Album`, but not for the `SignIn`. **Here's the catch, I wish to put the button on the bottom instead of on the top.**

The last remaining puzzle is how to add a `Sign In` button to the Bottom Navigation Bar.

The roadblock is if you write `<Tab.Screen name="Sign In component={SignIn} />` and you press a button with parameter `onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignIn')}`, it will navigate you to the `Tab.Screen` instead of `Stack.Screen`.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Album" component={Album} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen options={{title: ''}} name="MyTabs" component={MyTabs} />
      <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <MyStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the tabbarbutton like below. This would pass the props and render a the touchableopacity and you can have your own onPress.

You can navigate, here i have given an alert

```
    <Tab.Screen name="Settings"  
         options={({navigation})=> ({
           tabBarButton:props => <TouchableOpacity {...props} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('SignIn')}/>
    })}/>
```

Comment: This approach works great, thanks! But, latest react-navigation 5.x requires a component prop to be defined in the Screen component. Using an empty placeholder component will work if you're trying this and it is throwing an error.

Comment: Just wanted to add onto what @CraigSturgis said. The component property would look like `component={ButtonScreen}` and `ButtonScreen` would look like `const ButtonScreen = () => null;`