# Add custom button to react navigation bottomTabNavigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a Tab Navigator that includes a button that doesn't link to a tab component, but instead on an onPress effect that links to a page in a stack navigator.

Here's a picture of what I'm needing to create for reference:

[image]

I came across this post ([How to add Button to a BottomTabNavigator on React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63895779/how-to-add-button-to-a-bottomtabnavigator-on-react-native)) and it seems to have a similar goal, but when I try to implement this solution, it is still looking for a component (error).

Is there a good way to do this? My navigator looks something like this:

```
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Discover" component={DiscoverScreen} />

//need custom button component here

        <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />


      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish it by rendering a custom tab bar using the tabBar prop.

```
  <Tab.Navigator tabBar={_renderTabBar} >
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Discover" component={DiscoverScreen} />

    //Use A placeholder component here 
    //We will replace its buttonlater
    <Tab.Screen name="PlaceholderScreen" component={PlaceholderComponent} />

    <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
```

From [React Navigation oficial website you can get the implementation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#tabbaroptions)

```
function MyTabBar({ state, descriptors, navigation, position }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
      
      //Substitute the Placeholder Button with the desired View
      if(index == 2){
        return <Button />
      }
      ....
```

Answer (score 1):

First create put a custom button component in your Tab.Navigator

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Discover" component={DiscoverScreen} />

    <Tab.Screen name="stackScreens" component= {stackScreens} />  //your custom component

    <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
  <NavigationContainer>
<Tab.Navigator>
```

When user tap into the middle button they will redirect to a stacked screens. Now you have to create a component that will use stack navigator to show multiple stack screens.
Here is a code snippet for our *stackScreens* component

```
const plusStack = createStackNavigator();  // creating stack navigator instance

function stackScreens() {
  return (
    <plusStack.Navigator>
      <plusStack.Screen name="stackScreen1" component={stackScreen1} />
      <plusStack.Screen name="stackScreen2" component={stackScreen2} />
    </plusStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function stackScreen2() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center',  alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>stackScreen2</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
function stackScreen1({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>plus screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to stackScreen2"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('stackScreen2')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here is a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@pieamo/stacknavigatorintabnavigator)

Comment: @Tobias if the answer solves your issue, kindly accept it (answers take up valuable time for respondents) - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)